# Node JS Soap Server(node-soap) passing values from postgres callback

Tags: node.js, soap, pg-promise

I have a question I am using node-soap and pg-promise. I have a problem where when I make a request to the soap service the response is delayed, in other words I have to send the request twice (using soap ui) before the response comes back:

Im wondering if I am not passing the response from the database call correctly to node soap call back:

Here is the sample code from node-soap website:

```
var myService = {
    MyService: {
        MyPort: {
            MyFunction: function(args) {
              return {
                  name: args.name
              };
            },

            // This is how to define an asynchronous function.
            MyAsyncFunction: function(args, callback) {
              // do some work
              callback({
                  name: args.name
              });
            },

            // This is how to receive incoming headers
            HeadersAwareFunction: function(args, cb, headers) {
              return {
                  name: headers.Token
              };
            },

            // You can also inspect the original `req`
            reallyDeatailedFunction: function(args, cb, headers, req) {
              console.log('SOAP `reallyDeatailedFunction` request from  + req.connection.remoteAddress);
              return {
                  name: headers.Token
              };
            }
        }
    }
};

var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('myservice.wsdl', 'utf8'),
server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
  response.end("404: Not Found: " + request.url);
});
```

Here is my code:

```
                        var http = require('http');
                        var soap = require('soap');
                        global.results = '';


                        var promise = require('bluebird'); // 
                        var options = {
                        promiseLib: promise // switch to bluebird lib
                    };

                    // Database connection details;
                    var cn = {
                        host: '',
                        port: 5432,
                        database: '',
                        user: '',
                        password: ''
                    };


                       var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);

                       var db = pgp(cn);


                       var cancelService = {
                        cancelService: {
                            Cancel_PortType: {
                                getAgreement: function(args,callback,headers) {


                                    var values = {
                                            vin: args.vin
                                    };

                                    db.any("select contract_num as contract, " +
                                        "CASE WHEN sg_con_status='A' THEN 'Active ' " +
                                        "WHEN sg_con_status='X' THEN 'Expired' " +
                                        "WHEN sg_con_status='C' THEN 'Cancelled' " +
                                        "END AS agreementStatus, " +
                                        "tfs_product_type as productType, " +
                                        "vin, cust_first_name as customerFirstName,    cust_last_name as customerLastName," +
                                        "TO_CHAR(original_busdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') as purchaseDate,   TO_CHAR(expire_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') as expirationDate " +
                                        "from tfs_contract_summary, sg_con_m1 where sg_con_m1.sg_con_contract = tfs_contract_summary.contract_num " +
                                        " AND vin = ${vin}",values)

                                    .then(function(data) {

                                    //set value of DB return to global
                                         global.results = data;

                                        console.log("DATAAAAAAA:", data);

                                    })


                                    .catch(function(error) {
                                            console.log("ERROR:", error); // print the error;
                                        })
                                        .finally(function() {

                                            pgp.end(); //closing the connection pool.

                                        });


                                    //  }



                                    callback({
                                        contracts: global.results
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('CancelService.wsdl', 'utf8'),
                        server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
                            response.end("404: Not Found: " + request.url)


                        });


                    server.listen(8000);
                    soap.listen(server, '/wsdl', cancelService, xml);
```

All of my console.log() show the data coming back everytime I fire off a request in SOAPUI but the response does not come back until the 2 time I sent the request:

For example

Hit button once:
vin = 12312364812736498

I expect John doe info to return -
**console.log(John doe's info)**
**SOAP RESPONSE = empty**

Hit Button twice
**console.log(John doe's info)**
SOAP RESPONSE = John doe's info

If I use the soap client sample code provided and issue a request:

console.log works everytime:

Do I have a scope issue where the global.results value has a race condition???

I'm pretty sure it's probably something wrong with my code as I am a newbie to Node JS etc...

Am I passing to the callback of the soap-server incorrectly??

```
callback({
            contracts: global.results
         });
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aaron's answer is correct, your `callback` is synchronous, sitting outside the  asynchronous promise chain.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to signoff of Aarons answer. I really appreciate the help in this community. I was hoping my question was not a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling the callback function before you set `global.results` (even though it is at the bottom of your function).

All the code in your promise's `.then` and `.catch` blocks run asynchronously - meaning they are shuffled off to the event loop to be run later; AFTER the current code completes.

Here's the order of what happens in your code:

1. You start a database query that happens asynchronously
2. You call `callback({contracts: global.results})`. At this point, `global.results` is undefined.
3. Your database query finishes, the event loop executes the `.then`s and `.catch`es as appropriate. Here's where you set `global.results` (too late, of course)
4. You make another request to the service - this time, `global.results` is already set to the result from the last query.

Solution would be to forget about using `global` and put the callback in a `.then` of your promise:

```
db.any("my_awesome_sql")
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("DATAAAAAAAA!!!", data);
    callback({contracts: data});
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  })
  .finally(function() {
    // Cleanup
  });
```

Comment: Many Thanks Aaron! I appreciate you taking the time to explain your answer thoroughly. I have learned a lot about node and promises as a result. Thanks again!